# Why the sum of this following function is the linear function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes

At the binomial point process of 2-D, there is the fallowing the distance PDF between a point and n-th nearest points from the point.

$f_{R_n}(r)=2/R\times B(n+1/2,N-n+1)/B(N-n+1,n) \times \beta(r^2/R^2;n+1/2,N-n+1)$

where $β(x; a,b)$ is the beta density function. $B(a,b)$ is the beta function.
$N$ is the total number of points and $R$ is the point distribution range.

I add all these functions as follows.

$\sum_{n=1}^{N} f_{R_n}(r)$

So, the $\sum_{n=1}^{N} f_{R_n}(r)$ for $0<r<R$ is the same as the Linear function $f(r)=2 N/R^2\times r$.

I don't know why.

Comment: Could you define better or provide a link for what you mean by binomial point proess of $2D$?

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.313.2143&rep=rep1&type=pdf
This paper illustrates the binomial point process of 2D well.

Answer (score 1):

By your link, $R_n$ is the distance to the origin of the $n$-th nearest point from the origin. Notice that
\begin{align*}
f_{R_n} (r)
&= \frac{d}{dr} \ P[\textrm{dist}(0, \text{$n$-th nearest neighbor}) \le r] \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \ P[\Phi(B(r)) \geq n].
\end{align*}
Here, I am using the notation from the paper you linked, in which $\Phi(V)$ is the random variable that counts the number of points that are on $V$. Summing on $n$, we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N f_{R_n} (r)
&= \frac{d}{dr} \ \left( \sum_{n=1}^N P[\Phi(B(r)) \geq n] \right) \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \ E[\Phi(B(r))] \\
&= \frac{d}{dr} \ \left( N \cdot \frac{\pi r^2}{\pi R^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{2Nr}{R^2}.
\end{align*}
In the third equality, we used that each point has independently probability $\textrm{Volume}(B(r)) / \textrm{Volume}(B(R))$ of landing inside $B(r)$.